# Regex match ALL possibilities

Tags: r, regex

I want to create a regex that only matches if the line starts with "line_start" and then matches with all digits.

I currently have:

```
"^line_start.*?(\\d)"
```

with the text `"line_start 1 abc 2 def 4"` it will return `1` when I execute `str_match_all("line_start 1 abc 2 def 4", "^line_start.*?(\\d)")`, since I used the question mark to make it non greedy.
If I remove the question mark:

```
"^line_start.*(\\d)"
```

The regex call `str_match_all("line_start 1 abc 2 def 4", "^line_start.*(\\d)")` will return the number 4.

How can I define the regex in such a way that it will return ALL digits (so 1, 2 and 4)? Remember the line MUST start with `line_start`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?:\\G(?!^)|^line_start)\\D*\\K\\d+", x, perl=TRUE))
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/03M1UJ/1/) and [R demo online](https://ideone.com/tlSNzs).

It is a base R solution with a PCRE regex that matches:

- `(?:\\G(?!^)|^line_start)` - either the end of the previous successful match or `line_start` at the start of the string
- `\\D*` - any non-digit chars as many as possible
- `\\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `\\d+` - 1+ digits.

Comment: Using `stringr`, you could use `res <- str_match_all(x, "(?:\\G(?!^)|^line_start)\\D*(\\d+)")` and extract Group 2 value.

Comment: This could only be: `stringr::str_extract_all("line_start 1 abc 2 def 4", "\\G\\D*?(\\d+)")`

Comment: @AlvaroMorales [I doubt it is what OP expects](https://ideone.com/t3YzbM) as it also returns the text before the numbers.